# I am not able close alert in selenium

Tags: selenium

I have drop down and selected value from dropdown ,select is having onchange javascript function ,it will raise alert window .I am not able close alert in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

handle alert by using below code:

```
@Test
public void testAlertOk()
{
    //Now we would click on AlertButton

    try {
        //Now once we hit AlertButton we get the alert
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        //Text displayed on Alert using getText() method of Alert class
        String AlertText = alert.getText();
        //accept() method of Alert Class is used for ok button
        alert.accept();
        //Verify Alert displayed correct message to user
        assertEquals("this is alert box",AlertText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right, you aren't looking for anything contained in the alert, just a way around the alert and continue with the test.

```
try
{
    driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
    //driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss(); 
}
catch (NoAlertPresentException)
{

}
```